# Teradata Parallel Transporter writer Error in informatica

Tags: teradata, informatica, writer, utilities

I have a simple  mapping with TPT as writer , 
Teradata Parallel Transporter throwing the following error?

```
Message: [ERROR] Type:(Teradata DBS Error), Error: (<Table> must be empty for Fast Loading.)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the LOAD operator of TPT which can only load an empty table.  You will need to either a) delete all data from the table or b) use an operator that will allow you to INSERT/UPDATE to a table with data.  You can read more about TPT operators here: [TPT 14.10 Operators](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_10/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2436_082K/2436title.html)